# Why Use Random Parameters after the URIs of Static Files

Tags: wordpress, http, uri

I am new to web development and have observed something I can't figure out myself.

I can see many websites are using random parameters after the URIs of static files, for example, `image-name.jpg?asdhajksdha`, `style.css?ahj123hk`, and things like that.

What are the random parameters for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be a couple of uses.

One is to prevent caching. The random numbers fool caching servers (and the browser) into thinking that each request is for a new resource.

Another is that the numbers are actually an identifier that is used to track your behavior. The resource might not even be a static file (the server can rewrite the url before serving up the content). The "random" numbers are tied to keys in a tracking data base. Many email clients will prompt you about loading images that are links in order to help you protect your privacy from that kind of tracking.

Comment: Uhuh, have to say that's pretty smart! Thank you Ted :)